# Edittext in Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to capture the input from an EditText placed inside a Canvas. EditText has to be inside Canvas because all other elements are in Canvas. I am able to wrap EditText in a layout and draw on Canvas(as you cannot draw EditText/TextView alone on canvas) but not able to give focus to it and show keyboard. Any solution or workaround for this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know how you do that but for me if you've achieve to draw the EditText on a Canvas (sic!) it means that you basically extract the Canvas of the EditText itself and draw the information on your own Canvas. It means your EditText is not managed as an EditText anymore. That why you can't focus it or display a keyboard.

To solve your problem you have two possibilities:

1. Put your custom component and the EditText together in a RelativeLayout or any kind of ViewGroup so like that your EditText is still an EditText and you can have access to its properties (like request focus or display a keyboard) but in that case the EditText is not draw on the Canvas of your custom component.
2. You have to reimplement the behaviour of the EditText in your custom component. It means displaying a keyboard when the user click on the area where the EditText is supposed to be, and so on. But this is not a good option.

But why everything needs to be in a Canvas? Probably you need to rethink about your implementation as something seems to be wrong.